# ORA-24381 finding root cause

Tags: oracle

I faced this error Error message: ORA-24381: error(s) in array DML in doing insert operation. There is no exception handling involved in the sql. Can I know now the root cause for this through any view ?

My database is oracle 12c

Comment: Please edit the question and post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is similar [to this article](https://sqljana.wordpress.com/2016/04/19/how-to-resolve-ora-24381-errors-in-array-dml/)

> I figured that my problem had to do Oracle’s bad estimation of the string length (that led to the issue).
>   So, I forced a `CAST` to limit the string to 30 characters and the issue went away!
>
> ```
> SELECT NVL(MAX(USERNAME),
>            CAST('NOT_THERE' AS VARCHAR2(30))
>           ) as usr1
> FROM DBA_USERS
> WHERE USERNAME = 'AN_USER_ID'
> ```
>
> In your case, the problem might be a similar data length issue and you might be able to resolve it too with a simple cast.

Comment: I am having an insert operation not a select

Comment: @EXODIA could you edit your question with more details on what operation you are doing?